# How to merge another select query in union

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries in first query count output show base on product wise

```
select 'Retail' as product  ,count(1) as policy_count  from g_hdfclms where lead_status in('rtp','qc_pr') and lead_id_lms not like ('%_01')
union
select 'Group' As [Group],count(1) as grp_policy from g_proposal_m where lead_status in('rtp','qc_pr')
union
select 'Renewal' As Renewal, count (1) as policy_renewal  from g_hdfclms where lead_status in('rtp','qc_pr') and lead_id_lms like ('%_01')
```

while another query is that output is merge and show total count of every product

```
 select(select count(*) as retail_policy from g_hdfclms where lead_status in('rtp','qc_pr') and lead_id_lms not like ('%_01'))
+(select count(1) as grp_policy from g_proposal_m where lead_status in('rtp','qc_pr'))
+(select count (*) as policy_renewal  from g_hdfclms where lead_status in('rtp','qc_pr') and lead_id_lms like '%_01')
AS total_policy
```

[image]
**Now i want to show Total_policy count and product wise count in same query im tried various method but fail to execute**

Comment: Have you tried [`WITH ROLLUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql)? This will return the total as the last row in the result with product `NULL`.

Comment: Using `UNION ALL` would make more sense too, there's no need to use the overhead of `UNION`, as there won't be any duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're last sql statement should return the same columns, then you can use another union.

```
select 'Total' as product, (select count(*) as retail_policy from g_hdfclms where 
lead_status in('rtp','qc_pr') and lead_id_lms not like ('%_01'))
+(select count(1) as grp_policy from g_proposal_m where lead_status in('rtp','qc_pr'))
+(select count (*) as policy_renewal  from g_hdfclms where lead_status 
in('rtp','qc_pr') and lead_id_lms like '%_01')
AS policy_count
```